Conditioning a probability distribution on a certain event
Suppose I have a nice distribution given by its pdf $p(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is usually problematic to condition on sets with zero measure (eg the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox). Nonetheless, given a point $x^*\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $r>0$, I would like to be able to condition on $\|x-x^*\|_2=r$ with the purpose of then integrating. Namely something along the lines of writing
$$\mathbb{E}_{R\sim p(r)}[\mathbb{E}_{X\sim p(x\mid \|x-x^*\|_2=R)}[f(x)]]$$
for some function $f$, where $p(r)=\tfrac{\partial}{\partial s}P_{p(x)}[B_s(x^*)]$ is the pdf of the radius.
Is this valid? If not in general, what do I need in order to make it a valid operation?

I don't fully understand your notation, but there is a notion of conditional expectation where instead of considering on an event like ${R \in A }$ you consider on $R$ directly. Here, $E[f(X) \vert R]$ will still be random but in a sense a function of $R$. If then $X$ has a conditional density with respect to the conditional expectation you write it as an integral.
See for example chapter 4.1 of Durrett's book, https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf
